# blank excel export using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I ran this code to export the result of dictionary to excel but it return blank. What happen as I remember I could export dictionary to excel using the same code before.

```
import pandas as pd

allJobs = {'A':[1,2,3],
           'B':[2,3,4],
           'C':[1,3],
           'D':[3,4]}

Jobs = ['A','C']

JobsWithNums = {}


for jobs in allJobs.keys():
    if jobs in Jobs:
        JobsWithNums[jobs] = allJobs[jobs]
        
print(JobsWithNums)
## output = {'A':[1,2,3],
##           'C':[1,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(JobsWithNums, columns=['Jobs','Nums'])
df.to_excel("file.xlsx")


## excel output
##  Jobs    Nums
##  A       1
##  A       2
##  A       3
##  C       1
##  C       3
```

Comment: your code returns nothing, can you post the output that you're after?

Comment: i have edit the output that i want to see but i want it to be export to excel

Comment: your issue is that your arrays are of unequal lengths, its not clear what you're trying to do, but if you give some guidance then a good solution can be given, I think you need : `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(JobsWithNums,orient='index').T`

Comment: I have tried this method of having the orient='index' and the result was a pivot table, i combine it with the .melt() to unpivot the data but it does return some blank space of the key values that i dont want in my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
for key, value in zip(allJobs.keys(), allJobs.values()):
    if key in Jobs:
        JobsWithNums[key] = value
df = pd.Series(JobsWithNums).rename_axis('Jobs').reset_index(name='Nums')
df = df.explode('Nums') #per OP's comment on this answer.
df.to_excel("file.xlsx")
df

    Jobs    Nums
0   A       1
0   A       2
0   A       3
1   C       1
1   C       3
```

Comment: Thank, I would prefer the output for mat to be each Jobs for each Nums. For example: A 1 A 2 A 3  --- Sorry do not know how to format it here in the comment

Comment: Thank you. Turn out it was more complicated than what i originally though of using the pandas data Frame. Very appreciate it.

Comment: @Yogurt no problem, when you get the chance, please accept as the solution if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use pandas to read in your dictionary and do some basic reshaping and filtering using `isin`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(allJobs,
                       orient='index')\
                       .stack()\
                       .reset_index(0)\
                       .rename(columns={'level_0' : 'Jobs',
                                          0 : 'Nums'})


df1 = df[df['Jobs'].isin(['A','C'])]

print(df1)

  Jobs  Nums
0    A   1.0
1    A   2.0
2    A   3.0
0    C   1.0
1    C   3.0
```